# How to draw circle on texture in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drawing

I try to find and show corners using opencv and unity3d. I capture by unity camera. I send texture2d to c++ code that uses opencv. I detect corners using opencv(harris corner detector). And c++ code send to unity code corners points(x,y position on image).

Finally, I want to show these points. I try to draw circle on texture2d in unity. I use below code. But unity says that `Type UnityEngine.Texture2D does not contain a definition for DrawCircle and no extension method DrawCircle of type UnityEngine.Texture2D could be found`

How can I draw simple shape on unity3d?

```
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(w, h,TextureFormat.RGB24 , false);
    texture.DrawCircle(100, 100, 20, Color.green);
    // Apply all SetPixel calls
    texture.Apply();
    mesh_renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
```

Comment: _[It's not that hard](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html)_

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I draw a circle in Unity3D?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708395/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-in-unity3d)

Comment: I find a project. It draws circle, line etc. here [https://github.com/ProtoTurtle/BitmapDrawingExampleProject]

Comment: _"I find a project. It draws circle, line etc. here [github.com/ProtoTurtle/BitmapDrawingExampleProject] "_ - if that's an answer it's a `404 page not found` error sadly

Comment: remove  last character in url, it is "]". try again

Answer (score 11):

More optimized solution from @ChrisH
(Original one slowed down my pc for 2 minutes when I tried to draw 300 circles on 1000x1000 texture while new one does it immediately due to avoiding extra iterations)

```
public static Texture2D DrawCircle(this Texture2D tex, Color color, int x, int y, int radius = 3)
{
    float rSquared = radius * radius;

    for (int u = x - radius; u < x + radius + 1; u++)
        for (int v = y - radius; v < y + radius + 1; v++)
            if ((x - u) * (x - u) + (y - v) * (y - v) < rSquared)
                tex.SetPixel(u, v, color);

    return tex;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that after 3 years I returned back to google with the same question

Answer (score 4):

Just make an extension method for Texture2d.

```
public static class Tex2DExtension
{
    public static Texture2D Circle(this Texture2D tex, int x, int y, int r, Color color)
    {
        float rSquared = r * r;

        for (int u=0; u<tex.width; u++) {
            for (int v=0; v<tex.height; v++) {
                if ((x-u)*(x-u) + (y-v)*(y-v) < rSquared) tex.SetPixel(u,v,color);
            }
        }

        return tex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how one would go about creating just the outline? Other than detecting nearby pixels?

Comment: I figured it out. Draw another circle over top of it, but using clear, and smaller relative to the thickness you desire.