# How to draw multiple circles by using "LineRenderer"

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a code for a drawing circle with [LineRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31767755/9815471).

but I want to draw multiple circles  with different radius, I  used "for loop" but there is one circle instead of multiple

```
public float ThetaScale = 0.01f;
public float radius = 3f;
private int Size;
private LineRenderer LineDrawer;
private float Theta = 0f;


void Start ()
{
  LineDrawer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
}

void Update ()
{
 Theta = 0f;
 Size = (int)((1f / ThetaScale) + 1f);
 LineDrawer.SetVertexCount(Size);

 for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
 {

    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
      Theta += (2.0f * Mathf.PI * ThetaScale);
      float x = l * radius * Mathf.Cos(Theta);
      float y = l * radius * Mathf.Sin(Theta);
      LineDrawer.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0, y));
    }

 }
 }
```

Comment: define "there is no result" please, your code do not compile, the result is not the desired, if it's not, why? that kind of stuff ^^

Answer (score 1):

In every loop you always overwrite the same positions indices in the same line renderer. So you will always only have the last circle.

Note that it is also quite expensive to use `SetPoisition` repeatedly. As it says in the API you should rather work on an array and then use `SetPoisitions` to assign all positions at once.

**One thing is a bit unclear though**: If you use one single `LineRenderer` you won't get independent circles but they will always be connected at some point. Otherwise you would need 5 separated `LineRenderer` instances.

#### Option A: 5 circles but connected to each other since part of a single `LineRenderer`

```c#
void Start ()
{
    LineDrawer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    LineDrawer.loop = false;

    Theta = 0f;
    // Use one position more to close the circle
    Size = (int)((1f / ThetaScale) + 1f) + 1;

    LineDrawer.positionCount = 5 * Size;
    var positions = new Vector3[5 * Size];

    for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
       {
           Theta += (2.0f * Mathf.PI * ThetaScale);
           float x = l * radius * Mathf.Cos(Theta);
           float y = l * radius * Mathf.Sin(Theta);

           positions[5 * l + i] = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
        }
    }

    LineDrawer.SetPositions(positions);
}
```

#### Option B: 5 separated circles in 5 separated `LineRenderer`s

```c#
// Drag 5 individual LineRenderer here via the Inspector
public LineRenderer[] lines = new LineRenderer[5];

void Start ()
{
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        line.loop = true;

        Theta = 0f;
        Size = (int)((1f / ThetaScale) + 1f);
 
        line.positionCount = Size;

        var positions = new Vector3[Size];

        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            Theta += (2.0f * Mathf.PI * ThetaScale);
            float x = l * radius * Mathf.Cos(Theta);
            float y = l * radius * Mathf.Sin(Theta);

            positions[5 * l + i] = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
        }

        line.SetPositions(positions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed few details here and there. Here, this will work:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent( typeof(LineRenderer) )]
public class CircularBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField][Min(3)] int _numSegments = 16;
    [SerializeField][Min(1)] int _numCircles = 5;
    [SerializeField] float _radius = 3f;
    LineRenderer _lineRenderer;
    void Awake ()
    {
        _lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        _lineRenderer.loop = false;
        _lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = false;
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        const float TAU = 2f * Mathf.PI;
        float theta = TAU / (float)_numSegments;
        int numVertices = _numSegments + 1;
        _lineRenderer.positionCount = numVertices * _numCircles;
        
        int vert = 0;
        for( int l=1 ; l<=_numCircles ; l++ )
        {
            float r = _radius * (float)l;
            for( int i=0 ; i<numVertices ; i++ )
            {
                float f = theta * (float)i;
                Vector3 v = new Vector3{ x=Mathf.Cos(f) , y=Mathf.Sin(f) } * r;
                _lineRenderer.SetPosition( vert++ , v );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### But

as @derHugo explained, this is not what you're looking for exactly as all circles will be drawn connected.