# How do you display a radius around an object using sqrMagnitude

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to get a radius to display around an object I want to be able to set one variable and set an object to match the radius of sqrMagnitude.

```
public class ObjectFinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private GameObject objectToFind;
    public GameObject objectRadius;
    public float radius;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update()
    {
        objectRadius.transform.localScale = new Vector3(radius,radius,0);
        obj1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("ObjectFind");
        if ((objectToFind.transform.position - player.transform.position).sqrMagnitude < radius * 1.75)
        {
            Debug.Log("Object Found");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Object out of range");
        }
          
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that the `sqrMagnitude` is as the name suggests **squared** so equals `magnitude * magnitude` ... you probably rather want to check for `radius * radius` .. or rather use `magnitude` which would also equal using `Vector3.Distance` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I draw a circle in Unity3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708395/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-in-unity3d)

Comment: I would actually prefer that the radius be a square and magnitude seems to get a round radius, only thing I can think of is adding rotation to another magnitude to make sure the corners are detected